# Webstorm 2016.1 Autocomplete without Ctrl + Space not working

Tags: autocomplete, webstorm

I am not sure if this was a change in one of the recent updates but I no longer get autocompletion suggestions **as I type** things like css selectors in a *.css* file or *js* function completion when typing `if`. This was the case for me about a month ago when I was working on my last project.

In the *Webstorm* settings, all I see is configuration using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Space</kbd> or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Space</kbd>

Is there a way to get the automatic *as-I-type* suggestions back?

Comment: Do you have 'Autopopup code completion' enabled in Settings/Editor/General/Code Completion? Please also make sure that Power Save mode is not enabled  (File/Power Save Mode) - when it's on, no auto-completion/inspections are available.

Comment: @lena Yes, I have that option enabled to popup after 1000ms but it doesn't seem to work - power save mode is also turned off. http://imgur.com/L3lGwLP